# DFS - Route between two nodes

Tags: c#, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I've constructed a Graph class with various nodes and directed edges between them.  I'm trying to run a recursive DFS algorithm where I'm checking to see if there is a path between two nodes.

```
public static bool RouteBetweenNodes_DFS(Node a, Node b) {
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return false;

    // If we haven't returned 'true' yet, we mark the node as visited and visit its children
    a.visited = true;

    Console.WriteLine("A: " + a.data + ", B: " + b.data);
    // We use this as our truth condition when we recurse.
    if (a == b) {
        Console.WriteLine("Match: returning true");
        return true;
    }


    foreach (var child in a.children) {
        if (!child.visited) {
            //Console.WriteLine(child.data);
            Console.WriteLine("Before recursion: " + child.data);
            RouteBetweenNodes_DFS(child, b);
            Console.WriteLine("After recursion: " + child.data);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

However, this isn't working. The graph looks like this:

[image]

And the console printout:

```
A: 2, B: 6
Before recursion: 8
A: 8, B: 6
Before recursion: 4
A: 4, B: 6
After recursion: 4
After recursion: 8
Before recursion: 5
A: 5, B: 6
Before recursion: 6
A: 6, B: 6
Match: returning true
After recursion: 6
After recursion: 5
Before recursion: 3
A: 3, B: 6
Before recursion: 6
A: 6, B: 6
Match: returning true
After recursion: 6
After recursion: 3
```

It seems that the value of the return statement isn't being propagated up to the top level for some reason.  I've also tried `return RouteBetweenNodes(...)` but that doesn't even search appropriately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest adding more `Console.WriteLine`s so you can see what's going on, something like `Console.WriteLine("Node A is " + a + " Node b is " + b + " entering foreach loop")` etc etc

Comment: Seems you don't use the return of `RouteBetweenNodes_DFS` inside the `foreach` loop, so the returned _true_ is only propagated once to the parent call, and then discarded?

Comment: @asp That is exactly right. I managed to figure this out as well. If you want to write an answer to this. I'll accept it.